# PHP variable declared global doesn't work within function

Tags: php

I am using a HTTP query string to pass an id. The variable I assign it to works perfectly for the queries immediately following. However, it doesn't work within any of the functions which I define in the same file, although I declared the variable as global.

```
$circleID = $_GET['id'];
```

`$circleID` works well for this query:

```
// Retrieve circle data
$circleDataResult = mysqli_query($connection,"  SELECT     name, description
                                                FROM       circle
                                                WHERE      circleID = '$circleID' ");

$circleData = mysqli_fetch_array($circleDataResult);
$circleName = $circleData['name'];
$circleDesc = $circleData['description'];
```

It doesn't work within the following function though. `$circleID` seems to be empty in this context:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
  $action = $_POST['action'];
  switch($action) {
      case 'removeUser' : removeUser(); break;
      case 'makeAdmin' : makeAdmin(); break;
      case 'revokeAdmin' : revokeAdmin(); break;
      case 'makeOwner' : makeOwner(); break;
  }
}

function removeUser(){
    global $connection;
    global $circleID;

    $thisUserID = $_POST['id'];

    $removeUserFromCircle = "   DELETE
                                FROM       circle_participants
                                WHERE      circleID = '$circleID' AND userID = '$thisUserID' ";

    if (mysqli_query($connection, $removeUserFromCircle)) {
        echo "You removed " . getName($thisUserID) . " from this circle";
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($connection);
    }
}
```

Apologies if this is a trivial question. I am new to php and spent a considerable amount of time trying to solve this, but I'm stuck.

Comment: you sure you chose the right table? and where's the form for this?

Comment: You should prepare and bind and use `$_GET['id']` (it's a super global): http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Yes, if I hard-code the circleID value, the query works.

Comment: check for errors then with error reporting

Comment: you used a GET array in one that works but POST for the other. Your question is unclear as to what comes from where and how. You're also using `FROM       circle` but using a different table for the delete `FROM       circle_participants`.

Comment: before switch case ... please do print_r($_GET) and share....
I think when you sending POST request then query param [$_GET] u are not sending......

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just checked error reporting again: I do get an `Undefined index: id`. I didn't notice this before. The circleDataResult query is still working, which I don't understand.

Comment: someone popped an answer down there for you

Comment: @Fred-ii- The use of different tables is intended. I am using GET to retrieve the circleID that is passed in the URL and POST to retrieve a userID that is passed via AJAX.

Comment: @Naincy Yes, you were right, I get an empty array when doing this before the switch statement. Right after `$circleID = $_GET['id'];` it gives me this though: `Array ( [id] => 1 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See why this will not work

Suppose that you have sent an get request to a page

```
$a = $_GET['variable'];
echo $a ; // this will echo the variable
exit;
```

Now you are making once again the post request to this page

```
$a=$_POST['variable'];
echo $a; // will print data if there exist data in the given variable
exit;
```

Now since you want to access the previous get data in the post data you have to save the get data in the session since on the next request all the data from the previous request will be lost

so in starting of the page

```
session_start()
$circleid = $_GET['id'];
$_SESSION['cirlceid'] = $circleid;
```

and in the remove function

```
function removeUser(){
global $connection;
$circleID = $_SESSION['circleid']

$thisUserID = $_POST['id'];

$removeUserFromCircle = "   DELETE
                            FROM       circle_participants
                            WHERE      circleID = '$circleID' AND userID = '$thisUserID' ";

if (mysqli_query($connection, $removeUserFromCircle)) {
    echo "You removed " . getName($thisUserID) . " from this circle";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

}

Comment: I just tried this. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I do get an `Undefined index: id` and subsequently an `Undefined variable: circleid` in the error report. However, the first query still works. `echo $circleName` gives me the correct name.

Comment: @waldbaum paste ue exact code or share it using jmp.sh url

Comment: This is the exact code: https://gist.github.com/waldbaum/20010f96bb0e39145b1f9b794f2ac725

Comment: @waldbaum can u go check case for the variable that are being fetched from the request using if isset then only save the value for that $_GET['id]

Comment: I am sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by this. Could you explain what I should try to do in greater detail?

Comment: `code` if(isset($_GET['id']){ then set your variable here} `code`

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it!

Answer (score 1):

In order to sum up the answer for anyone else encountering the problem:

It seems like the id value I wanted to retrieve via GET from the HTTP query string value was overwritten/set to null by the POST request, as user3411846 pointed out. Thus, when the code was executed via AJAX, circleID was set to null. 
Using session variables in conjunction with `if(isset){}` solved the problem!

This is the bit of code I changed:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $_SESSION['circleid'] = $_GET['id'];
}
```

instead of:

```
$circleID = $_GET['id'];
```

And within the function:

```
function removeUser(){
    ...
    $circleID = $_SESSION['circleid'];
    ...
}
```

instead of:

```
function removeUser(){
    ...
    global $circleID;
    ...
}
```